# androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize - androidx.startup.StartupException

Tags: android, android-13

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=-19
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7974)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:7480)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:7238)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2296)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:240)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:351)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8422)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Caused by androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=-19
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize (AppInitializer.java:187)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (AppInitializer.java:238)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (AppInitializer.java:206)
  at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate (InitializationProvider.java:45)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2451)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2421)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7969)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=-19
  at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.nativeInit
  at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.<init> (DisplayEventReceiver.java:123)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.<init> (Choreographer.java:1329)
  at android.view.Choreographer.<init> (Choreographer.java:287)
  at android.view.Choreographer.<init>
  at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue (Choreographer.java:117)
  at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue (Choreographer.java:110)
  at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue (ThreadLocal.java:180)
  at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get (ThreadLocal.java:170)
  at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance (Choreographer.java:319)
  at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer$Choreographer16Impl.postFrameCallback (ProfileInstallerInitializer.java)
  at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer.delayAfterFirstFrame (ProfileInstallerInitializer.java)
  at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer.create (ProfileInstallerInitializer.java:82)
  at androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer.create (ProfileInstallerInitializer.java:64)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize (AppInitializer.java:180)
```

Most of the anomalies collected by the statistics platform recently were triggered on the "onePlus" mobile phone system. It is not clear what different restrictions the specific system has for "ContentProvider". I have no clue whether anyone has encountered this problem.

Only appears on Android13 systems！